# How to separate binary print outs in java?

Tags: stack

I managed to use stack to print of decimal to binary but i do not know how to separate the binary for every 4 it return, meaning this. if i want the binary of 123 = 1111011 is what it will print out, i want it to print out 1111 011 and so on for every 4 digits. Let me know if it can be done and please try to example it if you can im trying to learn!

```
import java.util.*;
public class SchoolHomework {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Program that converts decimal to binary!");
    int dec;
    System.out.println("Please type in a decimal number:");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Stack<Integer> todec = new Stack<Integer>();
    dec = input.nextInt();
    if (dec < 0){
        System.out.println("Error: Please enter a positive number!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    while (dec != 0){
        int stackv = dec % 2;
        todec.push(stackv);
        dec /= 2;

    }
    System.out.println(dec + " To binary is: ");
    int counter = 0;
    while (!(todec.isEmpty() )) {
        String val = todec.pop().toString();
        System.out.print(val);
        counter = counter + 1;
        if (counter >= 4){
            counter = 0;
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So guys in case you wanted to know, i figured it out. I used a tostring on it like this String val = todec.pop().toString(); that solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter(count from 4 to 0 or vice versa) in last while loop.

**Psudo code**:

```
counter = 0
while todec is not empty
    print todec entry

    counter = counter + 1
    if counter >= 4 then
         counter = 0
         print " "
    endif
end while
```

You better use [shift operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) instead of "div" or "mod" operators

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by instead of "div" or "mod"

Comment: Plus, when i implement that change, i do not get the correct binary return. Do you know why? i edited initial post with new code!

Comment: For both questions: because you are using`div` operator, `123/2 = 61.5` casting to Integer will drops some bits. Change to use shift operator will solve your problem.